# Can I add my React.Component subclass to ESLint rules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am working on a project which builds an ES6 React App with Webpacker. We're using ESLint to keep our scripts tidy with some pre-commit hooks, but there is one issue I haven't been able to resolve. We have a couple of `React.Component` sub-classes that we use and they aren't being detected as `Components` by ESLint.

Example Components:

```js
/* AsyncComponent.jsx */
export default class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
  // Sub-classes will define _render() instead of render()
  render() {
    if (this.isLoaded()) {
      this._render();
    }
  }

  // "Virtual" functions which must be defined by sub-class
  // isLoaded() {}
  // load() {}
  // _render() {}
}
```

```js
/* MyComponent.jsx */
export default class MyComponent extends AsyncComponent {
  // This works, but is not parsed as a Component by ESLint

  // Define our "virtual" AsyncComponent functions
  isLoaded() {}
  load() {}
  _render() {}
}
```

**MY QUESTION:** I would like to know if it is possible to configure ESLint to detect `AsyncComponent` sub-classes such as `MyComponent` as `React.Component` sub-classes and apply the same rules that it would to other `Components`.

**BONUS QUESTION:** This may cause an issue with the `_render()` method that this particular example uses, so it would also be helpful if I could override the eslint-react rules to expect `_render()` instead of `render()` within `AsyncComponent` sub-classes.

Relevant dependencies from `package.json`:

```
"eslint": "^5.11.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.2",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-redux": "^3.0.1",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
```

Relevant config from `.eslintrc`:

```
"extends": [
  "airbnb",
  "plugin:react-redux/recommended",
  "plugin:promise/recommended"
],
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 8,
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
    "impliedStrict": true,
    "classes": true
  }
},
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true,
  "jquery": true,
  "jest": true
},
"plugins": [
  "react-redux",
  "promise"
],
```

Comment: You shouldn't extend one component with another - use composition instead of inheritance. Your approach is really dirty (and will be hell to maintain) - you should do HoC instead.

Comment: What does *they aren't being detected as Components by ESLint* mean? If there's an error, please, post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. I think you could try return super.render()

```
render() {
    if (this.isLoaded()) {
      super.render()
    }
  }
```

But its a bad idea to extend components like this as the above says use hooks, Hocs or renderProps patterns for this kind of stuff, I know it can be confusing , especially if you come from an 'OO' background, but taking the approach you have done will be more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fard for his suggestion. I was trying to do this the wrong way... seems like [React Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) are the right way to do what I'm trying to achieve here.